# How To Upload A File Using A Model in yii?

Tags: php, yii, image-uploading

i have read this article http://yiiframework.com/wiki/2
and i have done everything step by step .
but it's not working !
this is the model which i just copy and then paste :

```
class Item extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $image;
    // ... other attributes

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png'),
        );
    }
}
```

my view is exactly the same as the article :

```
$form = $this->beginWidget(
    'CActiveForm',
    array(
        'id' => 'upload-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
        'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
    )
);

// ...
echo $form->labelEx($model, 'image');
echo $form->fileField($model, 'image');
echo $form->error($model, 'image');
// ...
echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit');
$this->endWidget();
```

and my controller is :

```
class ItemController extends CController
{
    public function actionCreate()
    {

        $model=new Item;
        if(isset($_POST['Item']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Item'];
            $model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            if($model->save())
            {
                $model->image->saveAs(dirname(__FILE__).'/a.txt');
                // redirect to success page

            }
        }
        $this->render('create', array('model'=>$model));
    }
}
```

when i choose an image(jpg , png , or something else) the controller doesn't see my file , i mean `isset($_FILES['Item'])` is false ... i know it's false because i check it with `var_dump` hundreds of times :

```
  public function actionCreate()
    {

        $model=new Item;
        var_dump(isset($_POST['Item']));
...
```

i also test `var_dump(isset($_FILES['Item']))` which was false either .
for every kinds of file(except plain txt file)  `$_POST['Item']`) remains empty.

i checked my request using firebug network panel(both Firefox and chrome) and the request had the file .
i have already check this question , seems it's the same problem but the answers wasn't useful because `CUploadedFile::getInstance` and `CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName` are also return null for my case

what do you think ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was not related to Yii Framework or my php code because i just test the same code on two different machine and that works just fine .
i am using wamp on my own computer and i guess the problem was something related to Apache or php configurations.

Answer (score 0):

In controller change and use like this:

```
class ItemController extends CController
{
    public function actionCreate()
    {

        $model=new Item;
        if(isset($_POST['Item']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Item'];
            $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            if($model->save())
            {

                if(!empty($uploadedFile))  // check if uploaded file is set or not
                {

                    if($model->image == null || empty($model->image)){
                        $rnd = rand(0,9999);// generate random number between 0-9999
                        $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";
                        $model->image = $fileName;
                    }
                    $uploadedFile->saveAs(dirname(__FILE__)..'/images/'. $model->image);
                    // redirect to success page
                }
            }
        }
        $this->render('create', array('model'=>$model));
    }
}
```